# Adicionar indicador em abas do Materialize CSS

Tags: css, materialize, aba

Bom dia,

Estou com a seguinte nescessidade, tenho um projeto onde existiram
 muitas abas feitas com materialize css, porem em dispositivos de tela pequenas as abas ficam ocultas a direita da tela, sendo necessario delizar
 o dedo sobres o compo das abas para poder visualizar as abas restantes.
    Gostaria de uma ajuda para colocar um indicativo de que haja abas escondidas, como na img a baixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<head>
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">


    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>

<body>    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            <ul class="tabs">
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test grandão 1 </a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Test grandão 2</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3 "><a href="#test3">Teste grandão 3</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test grandão 4</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test5">Test grandão 5</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test6">Test grandão 6</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3 "><a href="#test7">Teste grandão 7</a></li>
                <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test8">Test grandão 8</a></li>        
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
        <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
        <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
        <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
        <div id="test5" class="col s12">Test 5</div>
        <div id="test6" class="col s12">Test 6</div>
        <div id="test7" class="col s12">Test 7</div>
        <div id="test8" class="col s12">Test 8</div>    
    </div>
    <!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.tabs').tabs();
        });            
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se quiser pode fazer assim, coloca um botão com ícones deixa ele não visível e quando a pessoa clicar na área do **tab** o botão aparece durante dois segundos e depois some. Aí vc usa **media queries** para esconder o botão na versão desktop.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.tabs').tabs();
   var seta = $('.seta');                // pega a seta
   seta.hide();                          // esconde a seta
   
   $('#tab').on('click', function() {   // pega o click na tab   
      seta.show().fadeOut(2000);       // mostra o botão e esconde depois de 2 segundos
   })
});
```

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {  /*apenas para funcionar aqui no site*/
  .seta{
    visibility: hidden;
  }  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
   <div class="col s12" id="tab">
       <ul class="tabs">
           <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test grandão 1 </a></li>
           <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test2">Test grandão 2</a></li>
           <li class="tab col s3 "><a href="#test3">Teste grandão 3</a></li>
           <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test grandão 4</a></li>
           <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test5">Test grandão 5</a></li>
           <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test6">Test grandão 6</a></li>
           <li class="tab col s3 "><a href="#test7">Teste grandão 7</a></li>
           <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test8">Test grandão 8</a></li>        
       </ul>
   </div>
   
   <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
   <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
   <div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
   <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
   <div id="test5" class="col s12">Test 5</div>
   <div id="test6" class="col s12">Test 6</div>
   <div id="test7" class="col s12">Test 7</div>
   <div id="test8" class="col s12">Test 8</div> 
   
   <span class="right seta">
       <a class="btn btn-small red">
           <i class="small material-icons">arrow_forward</i>
       </a>
   </span>
 
</div>
```